# finding children of excluding in a parent-child relationship

Tags: sql

I have a table X where there is a one-to-many parent-child relationship to itself that is handled by `parent_id` attribute.

```
| id | parent_id | type |
|----|-----------|------|
| 1  | -         | A    |
| 2  | -         | A    |
| 3  | -         | A    |
| 4  | 1         | B    |
| 5  | 1         | C    |
| 6  | 2         | B    |
| 7  | 3         | C    |
```

I would like to get all rows of type A that don't have any child rows of type B. What is the SQL query to obtain those rows?

Comment: In which database? you can use connect by prior statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    x AS t1
WHERE
    t1.type = 'a'
        AND 0 = (SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            x AS t2
        WHERE
            t2.id_parent = t1.id AND t2.type = 'b')
```